# Building and signing an Android bundle (.aab) using AWS CodePipeLine

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS CodePipeline set up and want to use it to generate a signed app bundle from an Android Studio Project.

The Android docs for [configuring gradle to sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#gradle_signing) indicate that you need to first generate a .jks file and use this and the gradlew command-line tool to generate a signed app bundle.

However, if I want to integrate this into my CI/CD process with AWS how would I store the .jks file as an environment in my build pipeline?

If it helps, I've already enabled [App Signing by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Hi, I did actually. I'll post an answer sometime over the next two days

Comment: @random_coder_101 I can't find any solution. Can u tell me where u have posted ?

Comment: @xaif - Yep, here you go - https://redixhumayun.github.io/programming/2021/03/24/automating-android-app-bundle-upload.html